# Gwt App took too much time for the first visit? How to fix it?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

I have just compiled my Gwtp app & tried to run in a Virtual Private Server.

In the War folder (after compiled) is a folder name `myproject`. In `myproject` folder there are about 14 `html` files all these 14 files cost 1MB. There is also 2 folders in `myproject`: `deferredjs` & `gwt`

- `gwt` folder costs about 50KB
- `deferredjs` folder has 10 different folders inside, each costs 2 MB so `deferredjs` has a total of 20 MB.

I believe that the files & folders inside `myproject` will be downloaded into the client. I am not sure how Gwt send the files to client, but at first time a user opens my website, then he has to wait for like 12 to 15 sec which is too long. However, it is very fast for the next visit normally take like 1 or 2 or 3 secs.

My project has 50000 lines of code. It was designed like this:

- Header presenter
- Content presenters (embedded inside Header presenter)

The Header presenter uses 131 icons but the all 131 icons cost only 240 KB.

What about VPS. My VPS has 1TB bandwidth a month. I don't think its VPS problem. So what is the problem that causing the GWT app too much time to show to user at the first visit? or it is just normal?

Can we do something about it?

Comment: Make sure that you are not checking load time in debug mode. Is the first page waiting on any other resources, like db connections etc ?

Comment: no DB involved in home page

Comment: Have you tried speed tracer ? https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/speedtracer/?csw=1

Comment: garbage collection mean?

Comment: This is not relate to gc. There is something specific in your page design which is causing this slowness. Its not a normal thing. With speed tracer you may be able to narrow down which portion of the code is taking long to load.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what code-splitting is intended for - to make the initial download your user has to do much smaller (and therefore quicker).  The other parts of your application can then be downloaded as they are required.

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html

Comment: then how to see the compiled report in eclipse?